# Getting io.realm.exceptions.RealmError for some users

Tags: android, exception, realm, realm-java

I am getting an `io.realm.exceptions.RealmError` for some users in my android application.

```
public Realm getRealm(){
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()   
            .build();
    return Realm.getInstance(config); //getting error at this line
}
```

realm version: 3.7.2
Please tell me how to fix that.

[image: Crash logs]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] *as text*.

Comment: @BaummitAugen
i've added code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i coded Realm was by initializing the default instance in the application using the following code.

```
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(REALM_DB_NAME)
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

An everytime i wanted to get an instance of realm i would use the following command.

```
Realm  realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```